# jquery calculations on mysql table results not working

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have an multi-tabbed app that I am building that calculates fantasy football scores depending on values selected in drop down fields. I have it working in 5 out of 6 tabs but I cannot get it working in the 6th tab. I was hoping that a fresh pair of eyes would spot something that I am missing:

```
<?php
// contact to database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "dariia", "celtic03") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");
mysql_select_db("football");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
function calcTFP(e) {
if(e) e.preventDefault();

var $tds, Sacks, Int_Caught, Def_TD, ST_TD, Shutouts, TFP;

$("tbody#dst tr").each(function() {
    $tds = $(this).find("td");
    Sacks = Number($tds.eq(1).text());
    Int_Caught = Number($tds.eq(2).text());
    Def_TD = Number($tds.eq(3).text());
    ST_TD = Number($tds.eq(4).text());
    Shutouts = Number($tds.eq(5).text());

    TFP = Number($s_sacks_pts.val()) * Sacks;
    TFP += Number($s_int_caught_pts.val()) * Int_Caught;
    TFP += Number($s_def_td_pts.val()) * Def_TD;
    TFP += Number($s_st_td_pts.val()) * ST_TD;
    TFP += Number($s_shut_pts.val()) * Shutouts;

    $tds.eq(6).text(TFP.toFixed(2));//display calculated points in row's TFP column
});
}

//Sacks
var $s_sacks_pts = $("#s_sacks_pts").on('change', calcTFP);

//Int Caught
var $s_int_caught_pts = $("#s_int_caught_pts").on('change', calcTFP);

//Defense TDs
var $s_def_td_pts = $("#s_def_td_pts").on('change', calcTFP);

//Special Teams TDs
var $s_st_td_pts = $("#s_st_td_pts").on('change', calcTFP); 

//Shutouts
var $s_shutouts_pts = $("#s_shutouts_pts").on('change', calcTFP);

calcTFP();//initial calculation on page load
});
</script>

<form id="calc">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td style="padding-right:33px"><strong>Sacks:</strong><br />     
    <div style="float:left ; text-align:center">
    <select id="s_sacks_pts">
    <option value="0">0 pts</option>
    <option value="1">1 pt</option>
    <option value="2">2 pts</option>
    <option value="3">3 pts</option>
    <option value="4">4 pts</option>
    <option value="5">5 pts</option>
    <option value="6" selected>6 pts</option>
    <option value="7">7 pts</option>
    <option value="8">8 pts</option>
    <option value="9">9 pts</option>
    <option value="10">10 pts</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left ; padding:9px 0px 0px 5px">per Sack</div> 
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:33px"><strong>Int Caught</strong><br />     
    <div style="float:left ; text-align:center">
    <select id="s_int_caught_pts">
    <option value="0">0 pts</option>
    <option value="1">1 pt</option>
    <option value="2">2 pts</option>
    <option value="3">3 pts</option>
    <option value="4">4 pts</option>
    <option value="5">5 pts</option>
    <option value="6" selected>6 pts</option>
    <option value="7">7 pts</option>
    <option value="8">8 pts</option>
    <option value="9">9 pts</option>
    <option value="10">10 pts</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left ; padding:9px 0px 0px 5px">per Int Caught</div>
    </td>   
    <td style="padding-right:33px"><strong>Def TDs:</strong><br />     
    <div style="float:left ; text-align:center">
    <select id="s_def_td_pts">
    <option value="0" selected>0 pts</option>
    <option value="1">1 pt</option>
    <option value="2">2 pts</option>
    <option value="3">3 pts</option>
    <option value="4">4 pts</option>
    <option value="5">5 pts</option>
    <option value="6">6 pts</option>
    <option value="7">7 pts</option>
    <option value="8">8 pts</option>
    <option value="9">9 pts</option>
    <option value="10">10 pts</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left ; padding:9px 5px 0px 5px">per TD</div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:33px"><strong>ST TDs:</strong><br />     
    <div style="float:left ; text-align:center">
    <select id="s_st_td_pts">
    <option value="0" selected>0 pts</option>
    <option value="1">1 pt</option>
    <option value="2">2 pts</option>
    <option value="3">3 pts</option>
    <option value="4">4 pts</option>
    <option value="5">5 pts</option>
    <option value="6">6 pts</option>
    <option value="7">7 pts</option>
    <option value="8">8 pts</option>
    <option value="9">9 pts</option>
    <option value="10">10 pts</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left ; padding:9px 5px 0px 5px">per TD</div>
    </td>            
    <td style="padding-right:33px"><strong>Shutouts:</strong><br />     
    <div style="float:left ; text-align:center">
    <select id="s_shutouts_pts">
    <option value="0" selected>0 pts</option>
    <option value="1">-1 pt</option>
    <option value="2">-2 pts</option>
    <option value="3">-3 pts</option>
    <option value="4">-4 pts</option>
    <option value="5">-5 pts</option>
    <option value="6">-6 pts</option>
    <option value="7">-7 pts</option>
    <option value="8">-8 pts</option>
    <option value="9">-9 pts</option>
    <option value="10">-10 pts</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left ; padding:9px 5px 0px 5px">per TD</div>
    </td>
</tr>            
</table>                                              
</form>
<p>* Note: You can sort Def / ST projections by any stat you like. Just click on the stat name to sort.</p>
<table id="table-def" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1" width="630">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align:center">
<th>Team</th>
<th>Sacks</th>
<th>Int</th>
<th>Def TD</th>
<th>ST TD</th>
<th>Shutouts</th>
<th>TFP</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="dst">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Team, Sacks, Int_Caught, Def_TD, ST_TD, Shutouts, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'Def' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr style=\"text-align:center\"><td>{$row['Team']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Sacks']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Int_Caught']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Def_TD']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['ST_TD']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Shutouts']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$row['Total_Fantasy_Pts']}</td></tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>      


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know I'm not willing to read this to figure out what's wrong.  Put a little more effort into telling us what you see.  What does "not working" look like?

Comment: Nevermind - I sorted it out. You are right, though. I did not explain the problem well. "not working" does potentially encompass a lot. Sorry about the vagueness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH! It was an oversight on my part.

```
TFP += Number($s_shut_pts.val()) * Shutouts;
```

should have been

```
TFP += Number($s_shutouts_pts.val()) * Shutouts;
```

Sigh...I've gone code-blind.